# Failed assertion: line 311 pos 7: 'field is String || field is FieldPath || field == FieldPath.documentId'

Tags: flutter, firebase

I have a streambuilder that I use to get the data from a collection. When I display the records in a view, the user can do a tap on a card. If he does, then, on the next view, I want to query the documents with a condition. The condition is based on the record id from the previous stream/ query.

I do not understand the error. I am getting a string and using that for the query.
If you can tell me what I am missing that will be appreciated. Thank you.

```
StreamBuilder(
              stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                  .collection('Users')
                  .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
                  .collection('area_of_Focus')
                  .orderBy("area_of_Focus_Name", descending: false)
                  .snapshots(),
```

```
child: ListTile(
                                trailing: IconButton(
                                   icon: const Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right),
                                onPressed: (){

                                  Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (context) => ProjectsListFocusV2(
                                       focusID: document.id.toString(),)));
```

```
Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                    .collection('Users')
                    .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
                    .collection('projects')
                    .where(['area_Of_Focus_ID'], isEqualTo: focusID)
                    .snapshots(),

                builder: (BuildContext context,
                    AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {

                  if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
                    return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                  }
                  else{
                    return  ListView(
                      children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((documentSnapshot){
                        return Wrap(
                            children: const [
                              Card(
                                child: documentSnapshot['project_Name'];)
                              ),
                            ]
                        );
                      }).toList(),
                    );
```

Comment: Try to remove `[` and `]` from around 'area_Of_Focus_ID', `where` expects a string (or the other options listed in the error message) here, and not an array.

Comment: Many thanks. I feel stupid not seeing the [ ]. Now it works.